# shell script transfer files to server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I have the script to copy file to server from my computer but when I execute, I must to enter the password, is there any way process with out asking the password from the user.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='myhost'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
for p in $*;
 do
scp -r myroot/filename-$p.drl $HOST:/opt/my_server_folder
done;
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into SSH Key Authentication I think [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password) might help.